# How do I get an Android application to use the Google API library in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api-client

I am trying to use Google's URL Shortening service in my Android app. I have imported the necessary jar files as mentioned [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/Setup)

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905262/to-shorten-the-url-using-google-api) as my reference to code from.

I am able to import the HTTPTransport class from com.google.api.client.http, but I am not able to import the GoogleTransport, GoogleHeaders, JsonHttpParser, nor Result, and JsonHttpContent doesn't seem to have the no-arg constructor given in the example I'm looking at.

Below is a screenshot of my project properties window, on the Libraries tab.
 [image: Project Properties]

Comment: Go to Order and Export and tick those libraries !!

Comment: Okay, I've done that now, but I'm still unable to import the missing classes.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all your jar files in your project libs folder. And remove these jars from Build Path Libraries as showing in image.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. The libs directory in Eclipse only displays "android-support-v4.jar", even though the other jar files actually are in that directory on the drive, and I'm now unable to resolve any of the classes when trying to import them.

Comment: If you copied jar files in application libs folder then it must show in that directory. Rebuild your app and go to properties--> Android Tools--> fix project properties.

Comment: Okay, the files are now appearing, after I deleted them and copied them back in via Eclipse, instead of via the OS's file system (why that makes a difference, I don't know). However, I am now back to the same situation in the code as where I was when I first asked this question - still unable to import some of the classes required.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can use the Google Plugin for Eclipse to add an API to an Android project, as detailed [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#Eclipse). Unfortunately, I still have the problem that I can't use the classes in any example I have found thus far. I guess I must just be using the library wrong.